# Bootstrap Inline-Horizontal Form Design

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to combine horizontal-inline features of bootstrap 3 form designs !

This is what I have currently,you can see that i have created an inline form

[image]

I want the checkbox element and an anchor tag for forgot password option like this . 
I found the example of what I want @ FB login form design

[image]

I have put my code @ [Bootply Example](http://www.bootply.com/127584)

Any Help would be nice guys !

Comment: Facebook uses table to get that form. You can use too.

Comment: Yes sir :) Am aware of it ! I would like a `bootstrap` way of doing it  :) Anyway I'd try that now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I could do with pure bootstrap:

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label label-default="" class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Email address</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2"
        placeholder="Enter email" type="email">
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox">Remember me</label>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label label-default="" class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword2">Password</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword2"
        placeholder="Password" type="password">
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
          <div>
              <a href="#">forgot password?</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

http://www.bootply.com/127634