# Navbar inline form bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a form like this:

[image: click here to see image]

This form is inside the navbar.It is in navbar top right.

In desktop layout 'forgot password' link should be started near password text box. In mobile layout that should be below the login button.

I am using bootstrap 3.

I have read this question [Bootstrap Inline-Horizontal Form Design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22878421/bootstrap-inline-horizontal-form-design) but **mobile** layout is different from what I need.

This is my [code in bootply](http://www.bootply.com/4E15pezTvE)

Comment: can you put the code

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using "push" and "pull" to order the columns.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering